# Boto3: create, execute shell command, terminate on ec2 instance

Tags: python, shell, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am newbie to **EC2** and **boto**. I have to create an EC2 running instance, where I can send a command with S3 file and execute a shell script.

I searched a lot and found a way with **boto** and **paramiko**. I don't know, whether it is possible to run a shell script in ec2 instance using boto3. Any clue or example in this reference will be a great help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boto.manage.cmdshell module can be used to do this.  To use it, you must have the paramiko package installed.  A simple example of it's use:

```
import boto.ec2
from boto.manage.cmdshell import sshclient_from_instance

# Connect to your region of choice
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')

# Find the instance object related to my instanceId
instance = conn.get_all_instances(['i-12345678'])[0].instances[0]

# Create an SSH client for our instance
#    key_path is the path to the SSH private key associated with instance
#    user_name is the user to login as on the instance (e.g. ubuntu, ec2-user, etc.)
ssh_client = sshclient_from_instance(instance,
                                     '<path to SSH keyfile>',
                                     user_name='ec2-user')
# Run the command. Returns a tuple consisting of:
#    The integer status of the command
#    A string containing the output of the command
#    A string containing the stderr output of the command
status, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.run('ls -al')
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between Boto and Boto3. The question specifies boto, but the question title says Boto3.

The accepted answer is correct for boto. But, for boto3, this question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645196/how-to-ssh-and-run-commands-in-ec2-using-boto3/45083322#45083322) :)