# How to access aws private instance through python3 using boto3 , paramiko

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am using the below command to access my instance. How can I achieve the same in python3?
ssh -i <aws_private_key> ec2-user@<aws_instance_private_ip> -o "proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p -i <aws_private_key> ec2-user@<bastion_node_ip>"

I have to run some commands after accessing the instance.

Thanks.

Comment: Relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645196/how-to-ssh-and-run-commands-in-ec2-using-boto3

Comment: I already looked into that thread and in that thread, public IP of instance needs to use. In our case, we have to use private IP so we need bastion node IP as well.