# How can I use Python (boto3) to determine which EC2 instances have CloudWatch agents?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am writing a Python script to determine which EC2 instances have CloudWatch agents installed and which do not.  I got some information from [CloudWatch Agent Troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/troubleshooting-CloudWatch-Agent.html#CloudWatch-Agent-troubleshooting-verify-running) but don't know how to implement it programmatically.  Do I use SSM, EC2, or something else?

Comment: [boto3 issue CloudWatch Agent #1448](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1448#issuecomment-449501485), shows few recommended API calls to check the same.

Comment: Thank you.  I will check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of external visibility into the status of a particular EC2 instance's CloudWatch Agent.

If your EC2 instances have the [SSM Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html) preinstalled then you could use boto3 to invoke [SSM Run Command](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command) to run a collector scripts on each instance ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645196/how-to-ssh-and-run-commands-in-ec2-using-boto3)).

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I want to do, but am not sure of which SSM function to use.

Comment: I linked the boto3 function. It's called `send_command`. This eventually invokes the Run Command feature of SSM afaik.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the boto3 function **send_command** is what I am looking for.  Thanks, everybody.